# Bulk Upload & Give same Metadata to all of them

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, metadata

Goal:
Is it possible to change the code in a way that when uploading mutiple files, the Metadata to appear only once and all the files being uploaded to get the same Metadata ?

How the code works

When uploading multiple files using drag and drop, a dialog box to enter the Metadata will show up ( which is the purpose of the code)

So if I upload 5 files using Drag&Drop  option, the Metadata Dialog window will also appear 5 times ( time consuming when there are lots of files being uploaded from lots of users)

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
(function (_window) {
    var maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc = 10000;
    function replaceUploadProgressFunc() {
        if (typeof _window.UploadProgressFunc != 'undefined') {
            _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc = _window.UploadProgressFunc;
            _window.UploadProgressFunc = Custom_UploadProgressFunc;
            console.log('replaced dialog');
        } else if (maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc > 0) {
            maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc -= 100;
            setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);


    function Custom_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state) {
        _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state);
        var messageType = ProgressMessage.EMPTY;
        switch (state.status) {
            case 1:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.VALIDATION;
                break;
            case 3:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADING;
                break;
            case 4:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADED;
                OpenEditFormForLastItem(state);
                break;
            case 5:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.CANCELLED;
                break;
        }

        function OpenEditFormForLastItem(state) {
            var caml = '';
            caml += "<View>";
            caml += "<Query>";
            caml += "<Where>";

            if (state.files.length > 1) {
                caml += "<In>";
                caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
                caml += "<Values>";
            } else {
                caml += "<Eq>";
                caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
            }

            state.files.forEach(function (file) {
                //only succesfull uploaded files that arent overwrites
                console.log(file);
                if (file.status === 5 /*&& !file.overwrite*/) {
                    caml += "<Value Type='File'>" + file.fileName + "</Value>";
                }
            }, this);

            if (state.files.length > 1) {
                caml += "</Values>";
                caml += "</In>";
            } else {
                caml += "</Eq>";
            }

            caml += "</Where>";
            caml += "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
            caml += "</Query>";
            caml += "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>";
            caml += "<RowLimit>500</RowLimit>";
            caml += "</View>";
            console.log(caml);

            var cntxt = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = cntxt.get_web();
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(window.ctx.ListTitle);
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml(caml);
            var items = list.getItems(query);
            cntxt.load(list, 'DefaultEditFormUrl');
            cntxt.load(items);
            cntxt.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                function openEditForItem() {
                    if (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
                        var id = item.get_id();

                        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                        options.title = "Add File Metadata";
                        options.url = list.get_defaultEditFormUrl() + '?ID=' + id;
                        options.autoSize = true;
                        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = openEditForItem;
                        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                    } else {
                        location.href = location.href;
                    }
                }
                openEditForItem();
            }, function (error, args) {
                    console.log("failed to get new uploaded items");
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(args);
                });
        }
    }
})(window);
</script>
```